# How to access a module on another controller in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

If I declared module inside an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) in Angular JS

```
(function(){
  var app=angular.module("myapp",[]); 

  var mapController = function () {
    var mapScope = this;

  };
  app.controller("mapController", [mapController]);
})()
```

How is it going to be accessible to another controller, which is defined inside another [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)?

Suppose I have another controller in a different JS file table controller. How can I access app module there?

```
app.controller("tableController", ["$http", tableController,commonService]);
```

In other words, can we create angular JS app without a single global variable where control are separated in multiple JS files?

Comment: What needs to be accessible in other controller? this controller (`mapController`)?

Comment: var app=angular.module("myapp",[]);  , this need to be accessible in another controller.

Simplest way is I will declare it a global variable and it's running fine.

But how can I access it , when it's declared inside an IFFY.

Comment: Just because you are in an IIFE doesn't mean angular doesn't have access to the window. See the code https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/module.suffix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where you want to access the module in the other controller, dont use the variable but instead use the module definition like this:

```
angular.module("myapp").controller("tableController", ["$http", tableController,commonService]);
```

This is because your `var app` is inside an IIFE which wont be accessible in the other controller file. But the module definition will work subject to the condition that it is already defined somwhere.

Comment: Working fine , Thanks a lot